# Android studio 3.2 canary Migrate feature

Tags: android, android-studio, refactoring, android-appcompat, androidx

I find two new refactor commands, what are the exact functions of

- refactor>migrate app to appCompat
- refactor>migrate to androidX

Comment: [migrate to androidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate)

Answer (score 2):

[Support](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/) (compatibility) libraries was changed to [AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/) libraries by Google.

So in the nearest future support libraries won't be supported anymore.

So "migrate to androidX" will do the following:

1. Android studio will change all imports in your class from **android.support. *** to **androidx. ***
2. Dependencies of your build.gradle will be also changed to relevant androidX libs

Comment: Hi, A small question. Is androidx good to use for production? I have around 7-8 external libraries/dependencies and i dont know all of them uses androix. So can i use androidx by just migrating my current project to androidx?

Comment: In the nearest future you have to do it.
But from my experience I do not do it know for some reasons :
1) Some libraries from android X do not have stable version (only alpha or rc)
2) There are problems with libraries with annotation processor that generating code from old support libs (for example ButterKnife)

So if all your libs analogs in AndroidX in stable release you can try to migrate.